# Compare 2 Columns if the the value in Second column replace it

Tags: python

I need to compare two columns if the value in the second column is 3 replace it at the first column, if its 0 in the second column then keep it

I have thses two column

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 0 |

it should be like this

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 0 |

Comment: load to table using pandas, use numpy np.where() to conditionly change the values

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean indexing for that. `df['B'] == 3` returns a boolean array that can be applied to column A to set the value equal to 3.

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,2,1,2,2,2], 'B': [0,3,0,3,3,0]})

    df['A'].loc[df['B'] == 3] = 3
    print(df)
```

Output:

```py
        A    B
    0   2    0
    1   3    3
    2   1    0
    3   3    3
    4   3    3
    5   2    0
```